Unable to use FaceID in an app running in single app mode
I have an app running in Single app mode. The app uses FaceID for some of its actions. I recently started using iphone 15, and in iphone 15 in single app mode the faceID does not activate, because the app is not able to use the applicationWillResignActive method.
older iphone's work just fine.
exiting single app mode also makes it work, however i am obligated to use single app mode for the app to work.
Any idea what can I do to fix this?
